# Finding rate of convergence by curve fitting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, finite-element, convergence, regression

I have some data: number of nodes $N$ and error in energy norm corresponing to it.

I have seen in some references that the rate of convergence is reported by

$$\| u-u_h\| _E=CN^{\alpha} $$

How can I find $C$ and $\alpha$ by MATLAB, I tried by :

polyfit $(N,\| u-u_h\| _E,1)$

But the answer was not true.

How can I find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, rates of convergence are usually given in the form
$$ \|u-u_h\| \leq C N^\alpha,$$
rather than equality. Furthermore, rates are *asymptotic*, i.e., only have to hold for $N\to \infty$. This means that you're unlikely to find a single $C$ and $\alpha$ such that your equation holds.

Another reason why your approach doesn't work is that what you're trying to fit is *not* a polynomial, since $\alpha$ is a) unknown and b) not an integer (for one thing, it must be negative since the error goes down as $N$ goes up).

What people usually do is look at a *double-logarithmic* plot: If you take the logarithm of your equation (or my inequality), you get
$$ log(\|u-u_h\|) \leq \log(CN^\alpha) = \log(C) + \alpha\log(N).$$
This is a linear polynomial $ax+b$ in $\log (N)$ with coefficients $a=\alpha$ and $b=\log(C)$ (from which you can find $C=\exp(b)$).

So if you apply `polyfit` to $\log(N)$, $\log(\|u-u_h\|)$, you should get an array $[a,b]$ with $\alpha=a$ and $C=\exp(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should be looking for a rate of convergence in the form
$$\|u-u_h\|_E \leq Ch^{\alpha}$$
where $h$ is characteristic mesh size. In your case, a rough estimate would be 
$$h = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$$
in two dimensions.

You need to evaluate the discretization error on several grids with decreasing $h$ and then use the polynomial fit as
`[alpha, C] = polyfit(lc, error, 1)` where `lc` is a vector of logarithms of characteristic lengths `lc = [log(h1), log(h2), log(h3), ..., log(hn)]` and `error` is a vector of logarithms of corresponding error norms.