# Calculate accuracy order/rate

Tags: error-estimation, numerics

I was doing error analysis of numerical scheme and I get $L_1$ error for each grid size with $N$ element. I was searching reference to compute accuracy order/rate from that error data but doesn't find any good reference. Anyone know?

Error:
$e=|u-u_{exact}|$

$L_1$ error:
$L_1=1/N \sum_{i=1}^{N} e_i$

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/finding-rate-of-convergence-by-curve-fitting-in-matlab

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you are asking. Are you saying that you have computed $e(h)$, the $L_1$ error as a function of the mesh size $h$ for several values of $h$, and that you then want to find $C,r$ so that $e(h) \approx C h^r$?

Comment: I have test my numerical methods with different grid size, coarse to fine grid. What I asked is how to calculate the rate/order like mentioned this link (see table). https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19746/28714

Comment: @Wolfgang yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

After read some new reference, using first order interpolation, accuracy order/rate simply calculated as follow:

$Order=\frac{log(e_1/e_2)}{log(h_1/h_2)}$

That's it

Comment: How is this answer different than the one given by @ChtistianClason in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21297/9667 ?